# my jsp page is not validating with result set rs=st.executeQuery();

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

```
This is my file name SEFHTML1.jsp

<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import ="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    padding: 14px 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Float cancel and signup buttons and add an equal width */
.cancelbtn,.signupbtn {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

/* Add padding to container elements */
.container {
    padding: 16px;
}

/* Clear floats */
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

/* Change styles for cancel button and signup button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .cancelbtn, .signupbtn {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<h2>Student Entry Form</h2>
<form method=post action="SEFHTML.jsp"></form>
  <div class="container">
<label><b>RegistrationNumber</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter RegistrationNumber" name="RegistrationNumber" required>
     <label><b>Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Name" name="Name" required>
     <label><b>Course</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Course" name="Course" required>
    <label><b>Batch</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Batch" name="Batch" required>
          <button type="submit" class="submitbtn">Submit</button>
    <%
String RegistrationNumber=request.getParameter("RegistrationNumber");
String Name=request.getParameter("Name");
String Course=request.getParameter("Course");
String Batch=request.getParameter("Batch");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","root");
ResultSet rs;
Statement st = con.createStatement();
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>90) rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customers1 WHERE RegistrationNumber='" + RegistrationNumber + "'Name='" + Name + "'Course='" + Course + "' and Batch='" + Batch + "'");
if (rs.next()) {
      session.setAttribute("RegistrationNumber",RegistrationNumber);
      session.setAttribute("Name",Name);
      session.setAttribute("Course",Course);
      session.setAttribute("Batch",Batch);

   out.println("Welcome " + Name);
   //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
    response.sendRedirect("facultyentryform.jsp");
}
else
{
    out.println("Invalid Details Please try again");
}
%>
<button type="button">Submit</button>
h1>Student Succesfully Logged in</h1>
```

My Problem is when i tried to validate RegistrationNumber,Name,Course,Batch it is showing me error at line 90(I mentioned line number in the code).I created a table called customers1 in mysql DB everything is fine in MYSQL DB.
The page has to direct from SFEHTML1.jsp to facultyentryform.jsp

facultyentryform.jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import ="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Faculty Entry Form</title>
<label><b>FacultyID</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter FacultyID" name="FacultyID" required>
     <label><b>FacultyName</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter FacultyName" name="FacultyName" required>
     <label><b>Designation</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Designation" name="Designation" required>
</head>
<body>
<%
String FacultyID=request.getParameter("FacultyID");
String FacultyName=request.getParameter("FacultyName");
String Designation=request.getParameter("Designation");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
ResultSet rs;
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","root");
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customers2(FacultyID,FacultyName,Designation) VALUES(?,?,?)");
st.setString(1,FacultyID);
st.setString(2,FacultyName);
st.setString(3,Designation);
int i=st.executeUpdate();
if(i!=0)
{
response.sendRedirect("bookentryform.jsp"); 
out.print("Welcome");
}
else
{
    response.sendRedirect("facultyentryform.jsp");
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Tomcat server exceptions

```
87: Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","root");
88: ResultSet rs;
89: Statement st = con.createStatement();
90: rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customers1 WHERE RegistrationNumber='" + RegistrationNumber + "'Name='" + Name + "'Course='" + Course + "' and Batch='" + Batch + "'");
91: if (rs.next()) {
92:       session.setAttribute("RegistrationNumber",RegistrationNumber);
93:       session.setAttribute("Name",Name);


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:588)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Root Cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name='null'Course='null' and Batch='null'' at line 1
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:669)
    org.apache.jsp.SEFHTML1_jsp._jspService(SEFHTML1_jsp.java:238)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Root Cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name='null'Course='null' and Batch='null'' at line 1
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3206)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1232)
    org.apache.jsp.SEFHTML1_jsp._jspService(SEFHTML1_jsp.java:208)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

This is apache tomcat server exception.I created a "customers1" mysql table/view in mysql.I have no problem in mysql table everything is working fine.I am using jsp,mysql and java.My page has to direct from SEFHTML.jsp page to facultyentryform.jsp.The following code above has to save in the mysql server whenever i try to give new fields

Comment: Do not use  jdbc directly in the jsp. Learn about three Tier architecture

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Your query is not correct,thats the error shown: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name='null'Course='null' and Batch='null'' at line 1
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)` please use 'AND' TO connect the column name and value.

Answer (score 2):

You miss the `AND` between the conditions:

```
rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * 
  FROM customers1 
  WHERE RegistrationNumber='" + RegistrationNumber + "' AND Name='" + Name + "' AND Course='" + Course + "' and Batch='" + Batch + "'");
```

And as I commented:

1. Do not use jdbc directly in the jsp. Learn about three tier architecture.
2. Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection.
3. Take care of the Java naming convention. Property names should start with lower case character

Comment: should i add between all the colomns name?

Comment: @KoushikReddy Yes it must be column name = value <operator> column name .... Where <Operator> is a Logical Operator like AND, OR, ...

Comment: should i add between all the columns or is their any specific.

Comment: @KoushikReddy Sorry can not get you

Comment: i solved according to what you said but now it is not directing to next page.

Comment: the error is cleared but now it is neither validating nor directing next page

Comment: @maybe you do not get any result? You make only a Redirect if you get an record from your db

Comment: Yes i am doing that it not directing to next page even though i usedresponse.sendRedirect("facultyentryform.jsp");

Comment: I used IN001 for RegistrationNumber,Koushik Reddy for Name,CSE for Course,2012 for batch.it has to atleast validate it right!!